# SQL to identify the last changed value in a column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to find the last changed value and the date when it last changed. A sample data looks like this below

[image]

I need a resultset like this

[image]

How can this be achieved with or without a LAG function? Either solution is fine

Comment: where did you get this LAST_CHANGE_DEPT=4/2/2016?

Comment: Sorry it should be the end_dt of Finance which is 4/6/2016. Corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select ThisRow.Id
    , ThisRow.BEGIN_DT as THIS_BEGIN_DT
    , ThisRow.END_DT as THIS_END_DT
    , ThisRow.DEPT as THIS_DEPT
    , PrevRow.BEGIN_DT as PREV_BEGIN_DT
    , PrevRow.END_DT as PREV_END_DT
    , PrevRow.DEPT as PREV_DEPT
from MyTbl ThisRow
     inner join
     MyTbl PrevRow
     on ThisRow.Id=PrevRow.Id
     and PrevRow.BEGIN_DT=(-- Find the latest begin date with a different DEPT value
                           select MAX(BEGIN_DT)
                           from MyTbl PrevRows
                           where PrevRows.Id = ThisRow.Id
                           and PrevRows.DEPT <> ThisRow.DEPT
                           and PrevRows.BEGIN_DT < ThisRow.BEGIN_DT)
where ThisRow.END_DT='9999-12-31'
```

This assumes that your final query is trying to get the 'current' rows (END_DT='9999-12-31')

Comment: Thankyou. This code works

Comment: @Ajcoder, you can then up-vote and accept as answer